# Using spherical coordinates, find the volume.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume, spherical-coordinates

Find the volume of the solid that lies in the first octant above the cone $z=\sqrt{3(x^2+y^2)}$ and inside the sphere $$x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=4z $$ using spherical coordinates:

So here is what I have done, I would honestly just like to make sure if I am doing this properly because normally the "cone" is written just as $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}  \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{4{\cos(\phi)}}  {\rho}^2\sin(\phi) \,{\rm d}{\rho}\,{\rm d}{\theta}\, {\rm d}{\phi}$$

$$= 2\pi \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \sin(\phi) \, {\rm d}\phi \, \left[\frac{\rho^3}{3}\right]_0^{4\cos(\phi)} = 2\pi \cdot 64 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \sin(\phi)\left(\frac{\cos^3(\phi)}{3}\right) \, {\rm d}\phi \\ = - 2\pi \cdot 64 \cdot \frac{1}{3} \left[\frac{\cos^4(\phi)}{4}\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} = - 2\pi \cdot 64 \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{4}\left[\cos^4\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) - \cos^4(0)\right] = \left(\frac{14\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{14\pi}{3}$$

Comment: You mean to find the volume enclosed by the finite region of the intersection of the cone $z = \sqrt{3(x^2 + y^2)}$ and the ellipsoid-ish body $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4z$.
Right?

Comment: yes except its a sphere

Comment: Corrected the RHS of sphere equation.

Comment: it was supposed to say 4z @Narasimham

Comment: At two places OP states it is a sphere.

Comment: @amcalde But this is the way the question was asked. You can change it to be $$x^{2}+y^{2}+(z-2)^{2}-4=0 $$

Comment: Oh wait, I had an error in my input. it is a sphere. I can see that now. Sorry. (Also an ellipsoid!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has azimuthal symmetry so I can immediately write:
$$I = \int\!\!\!\int\!\!\!\int_\Omega dxdydz =2\pi \int_{\theta=0}^{\theta_1}\int_0^{r(\theta)}r^2 \sin \theta d\theta= \frac{2\pi}{3} \int_{\theta=0}^{\theta_1}(r(\theta))^3 \sin \theta d\theta$$
The trick is to calculate what $\theta_1$ is (where do the surfaces intersect?) And also the function $r(\theta)$ which we can do via direct substitution.

$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = 4z$$
becomes
$$r^2=4r\cos \theta$$
So we have
$$r(\theta) = 4\cos \theta$$
The angle is calculated:
$$\theta_1=\arccos\frac{z}{r} = \arccos\frac{\sqrt{3(x^2+y^2)}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}=\arccos\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
So
$$I = 2\pi \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/6} \frac{(4 \cos \theta )^3}{3} \sin \theta d\theta = -\frac{128\pi}{3} \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/6} (\cos \theta )^3 d(\cos \theta)$$

$$I=-\frac{32\pi}{3} [(\cos(\pi/6))^4 - (\cos 0 )^4] = \frac{32\pi}{3}  \frac{7}{16} = 14\pi/3$$

So I get the same thing. Hopefully this is what you were looking for. Let me know if you have any other questions about my answer.

Comment: yes!!!! Thank you very much. @amcalde